# merging all columns in sas dataset who has column "shiyas" in header

Tags: sas

I have a sas dataset with columns `shiyas1`,`shiyas2`,`shiyas3` in it. That dataset has some other columns also. I want to combine all  the columns with header with `shiyas` in it.

We can't use `cats(shiyas1,shiyas2,shiyas3)` because similar datasets have columns upto `shiyas10`. As I am generating general sas code, we cannot use `cats(shiyas1,shiyas2 .... shiyas10)`.

So how can we do this?

When I tried to use `cats(shiyas1,shiyas2 .... shiyas10)`, eventhough my dataset have columns upto `shiyas3`, it created columns `shiyas4` to `shiyas10` with `.` filled in them.

SO one solution is to combine `shiyas` till the dataset have or to delete the unnecessary `shiyas` columns...

Pls help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use variable list.

```
data have;
    input (shiyas1-shiyas3) (:$1.);
    cards;
 1 2 3
 ;

data want;
    set have;
    length cat_shiyas $ 100 /*large enough to hold the content*/
    ;
    cat_shiyas=cats(of shiyas:);
run;
```

Comment: It worked for once and it stopped working. Now notes are shown in log similar to this "Invalid numeric data, 'IT/ITES/BPO.' , at line 4238 column 21."

Comment: @AbdulShiyas Sounds like you have some other problem; nothing in that code should do anything with numeric data.

Comment: @Joe Actually, I tried "cat_shiyas=cats(of shiyas:);" alone in the beginning.

Then I tried "length cat_shiyas $ 100;
    cat_shiyas=cats(of shiyas:);" . Now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use the `of` statement (which lets you read across a row, similar to arrays) with the `:` wildcard operator.  This will concatenate all columns beginning with 'shiyas'

`cats(of shiyas:)`

Comment: It worked for once and it stopped working. Now  notes are shown in log similar to this "Invalid numeric data, 'IT/ITES/BPO.' , at line 4238 column 21."

Comment: proc import datafile='D:\Shiyas\1.csv'
out=out.datafile
dbms=csv replace ; 
guessingrows=200;   
datarow=3;/*DATA FROM THIRD ROW ONLY*/                                                                                                                                
data out.chg; 
set out.datafile; 
Profession_combined=cats (of profession:);

Comment: Profession_combined is created, but the datas are "." (dots) only. But once it run with the values.

Comment: You want to predefine 'Profession_combined' as Char, with a large enough length. See my code above.